# Why resizing image using sharp not working when downloading image from s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, base64, sharp

I am currently using sharp to resize images in my bucket. I download the images from my bucket using a presigned url. The result is a base 64 encoded string which is saved in a variable. When I try to resize my image using the following code:

```
 const file = await fetchS3Object(result);
 //// Fetched file ////
    if (file.mimeType.indexOf('image/') > -1)
    {
        //// Compress image with sharp and upload to s3 //// 
        const compressedFile = sharp(file.response)
            .jpeg({ progressive: true, force: false })
            .png({ progressive: true, force: false }).resize({ width: 320, height: 320, 
         fit: 'contain' })
     }
```

However, i recieve the following error:

```
Error: Input file contains unsupported image format
```

Any explanation. What I want to do is resize my base64 encoded string and save it to another variable

The Implementation of fetchS3Object

```
  const result = await fetch(key, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
})

const response = await result.text();
const parts = response.split(';');
const mimType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
const imageData = parts[1].split(',')[1];
return { response, mimType, imageData }.
```

Comment: I'm only aware of `s3.getObject()` . How is `fetchS3Object()` implemented?

Comment: This returns a promise from the s3.getobject

Comment: s3.getObject returns the content `Buffer` in `Body` property, do you handle that in `fetchS3Object()` as well ? You have to pass that to `sharp()`

Comment: the file.response is the downloaded base64 image from s3

Comment: s3 javascript sdk doesn't mention anything about returning base64 and sharp also doesn't accept base64 string as I'm aware of. Please share the `fetchS3Object` implementation if possible

Comment: sorry I have been mistaken the s3 object fetch the presigned url from s3.getObject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213278/discussion-between-thee-sritabtim-and-ahmed).